# Class file don't run

Tags: java, classpath

```
C:\Users\student3>java -cp C:\users\student3 start
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: start (wrong name: wo
rk/start)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

screenshot: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/835/mt6a.png/
It's my first run class by windows, what happens?

**UPDATE:**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row so.. should i create 1 hundred directories?

Comment: Is it use package work; ?

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't think it's quite the same, that one is due to lack of classpath, this one is a package issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the part that says "wrong name: work/start". That means the class file is found but it contains a class called "work.start", but you wanted to run one that's called just "start".

You can do two things:

1. Create a directory called work and move the start.class file there. Run with "java work.start".
2. Remove the package declaration from start.java and recompile.

Comment: Can i create java icon with "-cp" parameter ? Is it possible?

Comment: This site works better if you post a question for each question you have. Also, what's "java icon"?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row 
so.. how to pick up the library? (Java icon(tag)- An icon is a graphic image, a small picture or object that represents a file, program, web page, or command. )

Comment: So you want to write software to create icons? That should be a new question.

Comment: why you ignore my second error?

Comment: Oh the `NoClassDefFoundError`? You have to add the .jar file that includes those classes to the class path, so the command line would be `java -cp .;path\to\something.jar start`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have placed the `start` class in a package called `work`.  In this cause you need to:

- Put `start.class` into a directory called `work`, and call `java -cp C:\users\student3 work.start`
- OR just remove the `package work;` line from your source file - then the command will work as you expect.

As a side note: Java class names, by convention, *always* begin with a capital.  So you should really rename `start` to `Start`.

Comment: Is it possible to create java icon with -cp parametr?

Comment: What do you mean, "create java icon"?  Since you've used it correctly I assume you already know that `-cp` sets the classpath.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row
so.. should i create 1 hundred directories?

Comment: i don't like to use  CMD  interface , can i create java icon with paramets -cp?

Comment: That's a separate question, you haven't said whether your first problem is solved.  You aren't being very clear you I suggest you ask a new question with as much detail as possible.